# Firebase Functions deployments get automatically cancelled by Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible that Firebase Functions deployments get automatically cancelled by Firebase?

We have simply run a deployment with:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

And we found that many database handler functions stops been called after some weeks.
This functions are listed in Firebase Console, but the number of invocations is 0.

With another deploy, the function return to work correctly, and respond to database changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a Cloud Function hasn't been invoked in 30 days, it will stop working.  This is a known limitation.

**EDIT March 22, 2019**: This problem has been solved, but you will have to re-deploy your functions in order to see a change in behavior.

Comment: I found the doc reference: https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas.
What would you do to keep many projects active? (projects that sometimes have 0 monthly calls). There's something better than re-deploy everything monthly?

Comment: Any chance this limitation will be removed?

Comment: *firebaser here* This limitation was removed as of today. You will have to redeploy your Cloud Functions one final time, but after that they shouldn't be auto-removed after 30 days anymore.